# SQL Server process suspended while executing simple SQL (one row deletes and selects)

Tags: sql-server

We have a problem on MS SQL Server. Processes get suspended. Looks like it is caused by simple SQL queries like Delete from x where id = @x, or select * from table where id = @x. Several similar parallel queries are being executed like delete one row. Process stays suspended. Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

[image: More details about processes]

In server reports no Locks or Blocks are reported. Process is suspending itself. There are no concurrent users or processes (it looks to me)

Comment: Any info about the table `x` its indexes and column id? Or maybe a query plan for the delete/select operations?

Comment: I wouldn't expect parallelism for a single row select/delete query unless no index exists on `Id` or the parameter data type is different. Make sure the parameter type matches the column. Upload your actual plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Today my colleague found "secret" article about Moodle configuration. Turns out we needed to set "Is Read Committed Snapshot On" to True. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're deleting one row, do you know the code that is being executed?  Could still be locking the tables you are deleting from.  Triggers that contain other triggers are notorious for this.

Cursors go row by row but they will put locks as well I believe so it might mean that tweaking the code is in order so that it's more set-based deletes and not row-based.